# Android gradle custom Plugin error after updating android gradle plugin to 7.0

Tags: android, gradle, annotations, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-custom-plugin

Following is my code for custom plugin

```
import com.android.annotations.NonNull;
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension;

import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration;


public class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

@Override
public void apply(@NonNull Project project) {
    project.getPluginManager().withPlugin("com.android.library", plugin -> {
        //code here
    });
}
```

}

After upgrading android gradle plugin from 4.2.1 to 7.0 above custom plugin code showing **error: package com.android.annotations does not exist**

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I work in the same project as alphanso and took over the AGP upgrade from him, here is what I finally found out:

The code sits in the `.buildSrc` directory of our project and is compiled there using the Gradle plugins `java-library` and `java-gradle-plugin`.

Therefore `android.useAndroidX=true` has no effect as this works only if you use the Android plugins, either `com.android.library` or `com.android.application`.

The root cause of the suddenly missing classes (we had a few other ones missing from sub packages of `com.android.build` as well) was somewhere else:

With AGP 7.0 most library dependencies of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` changed from "compile time" to "run time" as you can see here:

AGP 4.2.2:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/4.2.2

AGP 7.0:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/7.0.0

This means that when switching to AGP 7.x you must add the missing dependencies manually.

In our case adding

```
implementation "com.android.tools:common:30.0.3"
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In android gradle plugin 7.0, the use of AndroidX Libraries is recommended. First, in your gradle.properties file, enable AndroidX by adding

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Add these dependencies also (To set up the other androidx libraries),

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

Sync your gradle files and then change the import `com.android.annotations.NonNull` to `androidx.annotations.NonNull`